# How to combine rows under certain conditions postgres Sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, rows

I have a question. Below is my sql.

```
SELECT upniki.naziv,
        (
            SELECT count(caseid) 
            FROM terjatve, paket 
            WHERE terjatve.stevilkapaketa=paket.id_paket
            AND terjatve.idnarocnik=upniki.id_upnik
            AND paket.datum_predaje >='1900-03-01'
            AND paket.datum_predaje <='2020-03-31' 
            GROUP BY upniki.naziv) as st_vseh_primerov,
        (
            SELECT sum(racuni.startsum) 
            FROM racuni, paket, terjatve 
            WHERE terjatve.stevilkapaketa=paket.id_paket 
            AND terjatve.caseid=racuni.caseid
            AND terjatve.idnarocnik=upniki.id_upnik 
            AND paket.datum_predaje >='1900-03-01'
            AND paket.datum_predaje <='2020-03-31' 
            GROUP BY upniki.naziv) as glavnica_vseh_primerov,
        (
            SELECT count(caseid) 
            FROM terjatve, paket 
            WHERE terjatve.stevilkapaketa=paket.id_paket 
            AND terjatve.idnarocnik=upniki.id_upnik 
            AND paket.datum_predaje >='1900-03-01' 
            AND paket.datum_predaje <='2020-03-31'
            AND terjatve.statusnacinid='1' 
            GROUP BY upniki.naziv) as st_aktivnih
FROM upniki 
GROUP BY upniki.naziv, upniki.id_upnik
```

With this SQL I get the result as follows.

```
naziv     st_vseh_primerov  glavnica_vseh_primerov  st_aktivnih
CLIENT 1       12                      7500                  0
CLIENT 2       10                     40000                  0
CLIENT 3       15                      5000                  0
CLIENT 4       16                     15000                  0
CLIENT 5        9                     12000                  0
CLIENT 6        8                     60000                  1
CLIENT 7        4                      3000                  0
CLIENT 8        3                     10000                  0
```

The result, I need, is to combine rows where st_vseh_primerov <=10 into a single row. Rows that are the subject of combining, would not be shown anymore. So, the outcome should be like this:

```
naziv      st_vseh_primerov     glavnica_vseh_primerov      st_aktivnih
CLIENT 1          12                            7500              0
CLIENT 3          15                            5000              0
CLIENT 4          16                           15000              0
SME               34                          125000              1
```

Please if anyone can help.

Br
R.

Comment: Are you familiar with `JOIN`?  You should use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use case for it.

```
select case when ( st_vseh_primerov is null or st_vseh_primerov <= 10 ) then 'SME' else naziv end as naziv,
       sum(st_vseh_primerov) as st_vseh_primerov,
       sum(glavnica_vseh_primerov) as glavnica_vseh_primerov,
       max(case when ( st_vseh_primerov is null or st_vseh_primerov <= 10 ) then 1 else 0 end) as st_aktivnih
from ( < your select above ) tmp
group by case when ( st_vseh_primerov is null or st_vseh_primerov <= 10 ) then 'SME' else naziv end;
```

EDIT: You could also use coalesce(). ie:

```
select case when coalesce( st_vseh_primerov,0) <= 10  then 'SME' else naziv end as naziv,
       sum(st_vseh_primerov) as st_vseh_primerov,
       sum(glavnica_vseh_primerov) as glavnica_vseh_primerov,
       max(case when coalesce( st_vseh_primerov,0) <= 10 then 1 else 0 end) as st_aktivnih
from ( < your select above ) tmp
group by case when coalesce( st_vseh_primerov,0) <= 10 then 'SME' else naziv end;
```

Comment: This one works but where in result of st_vseh_primerov is null, it should consider it as zero. How to achieve that?

Comment: Thanks, can I ask one more question? Why is by st_aktivnih max and not sum? st_aktivnih should also be summarized as same as st_vseh_primerov and glavnica_vseh_primerov.

Comment: I just correcte max to sum and erase "<= 10 then 1 else 0 end) as" and it is working like a charm. Thanks Cetin.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn your existing query to a cte or subquery, and aggregate in the outer query:

```
with cte as (... your query here ...)
select
    case when c.st_vseh_primerov <= 10 
        then 'SME'
        else c.naviz
    end naviz,
    SUM(st_vseh_primerov) st_vseh_primerov,
    SUM(glavnica_vseh_primerov) glavnica_vseh_primerov,
    SUM(st_aktivnih) st_aktivnih
from cte c
group by
    case when c.st_vseh_primerov <= 10 
        then 'SME'
        else c.naviz
    end
```

Note that you should not be using implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause); this is an old syntax from decades ago, that should not appear in new code. Instead, you should use standard, explicit joins (with the `on` keyword). So basically, something like this (coming from your first subquery):

```
FROM terjatve, paket 
WHERE 
    terjatve.stevilkapaketa=paket.id_paket
    AND terjatve.idnarocnik=upniki.id_upnik
```

Should be written:

```
FROM terjatve
INNER JOIN paket ON terjatve.stevilkapaketa=paket.id_paket
WHERE terjatve.idnarocnik=upniki.id_upnik
```